# How is the WritePrivateProfileStruct/GetPrivateProfileStruct checksum calculated?

Tags: winapi, ini

Windows provides a [WritePrivateProfileStruct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-writeprivateprofilestructa) API which can be used to write binary data to an INI file, and a [GetPrivateProfileStruct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestruct) API which can be used to read that binary data back from the INI file.

The binary data is serialised in hex format, followed by a single additional byte which is a checksum. For example:

```
[ultravnc]
passwd=2AE0C448372D3C1CD2
```

in that case, the binary data is `2AE0C448372D3C1C` and the checksum byte is `D2`.

How is that checksum calculated?

Answer (score 1):

The checksum is calculated simply by adding up each byte, and using the result (mod 256) as the checksum. It is not using anything more sophisticated than that.